# Problem with finding the maximum value of a function

Tags: integration, trigonometry, derivatives, optimization, definite-integrals

> Question: I need to find the maximum value of the function: $\text{G}_\text{n}\left[\theta\left(\text{n}\right)\right]$, for some value of $\text{n}$. And for $\text{n}$, we know that:
>
> $$0<\text{n}\le\text{A}\tag1$$

$$\text{G}_\text{n}\left[\theta\left(\text{n}\right)\right]:=\alpha\cdot\left(1+\epsilon\cos\left[\theta\left(\text{n}\right)\right]\right)\tag2$$

For the function $\theta\left(\text{n}\right)$:

$$\frac{\text{n}}{\text{A}}\cdot\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{\left(1-\epsilon^2\right)^3}}=\int_0^{\theta\left(\text{n}\right)}\frac{1}{\left(1+\epsilon\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}\space\text{d}x\tag3$$

All the constants are known (except $\text{n}$ of course) and they are positive and real.

---

**My work**:

In order to find the maximum value, what I first did:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta\left(\text{n}\right)}\left(\text{G}_\text{n}\left[\theta\left(\text{n}\right)\right]\right)=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\theta\left(\text{n}\right)=\pi\text{k}\space\space\space\vee\space\space\space\theta\left(\text{n}\right)=2\pi\text{k}\pm\arccos\left(-\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)\tag4$$

Where $\text{k}\in\mathbb{Z}$.

When I asked Mathematica  the functions with the arccos, I got imaginary values, so that is not a possible solution:

- $$\text{n}=\text{A}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{\left(1-\epsilon^2\right)^3}}{2\pi}\int_0^{\arccos\left(-\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)}\frac{1}{\left(1+\epsilon\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}\space\text{d}x\tag5$$
- $$\text{n}=\text{A}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{\left(1-\epsilon^2\right)^3}}{2\pi}\int_0^{-\arccos\left(-\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)}\frac{1}{\left(1+\epsilon\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}\space\text{d}x\tag6$$

So, the only possible solution is (I think):

> $$\text{n}=\text{A}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{\left(1-\epsilon^2\right)^3}}{2\pi}\int_0^{\text{k}\pi}\frac{1}{\left(1+\epsilon\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}\space\text{d}x\tag7$$

For $\text{k}\in\mathbb{Z}$

So, is there a closed form for $(7)$?

Comment: Maximum of $G(\theta)$ is where $\cos\theta=1$, i.e. $\theta=2k\pi$, not $k\pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate
$$
\int_0^{2k\pi}\frac{1}{(1+\epsilon\cos x)^2}\,dx=2k\cdot \underbrace{\int_0^{\pi}\frac{1}{(1+\epsilon\cos x)^2}\,dx}_{J}
$$
let's calculate (by the standard substitution $t=\tan\frac{x}{2}$)
$$
I(a)=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{1}{a+\epsilon\cos x}\,dx=\left[\frac{2}{\sqrt{a^2-\epsilon^2}}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{a-\epsilon}{a+\epsilon}}\tan\frac{x}{2}\right)\right]_0^{\pi}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-\epsilon^2}}.
$$
Then 
$$
J=-I'(1)=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{(1-\epsilon^2)^3}}.
$$
So I got (7) with $2k\pi$ in the integration limit as
$$
n=Ak.
$$
Together with $0<n\le A$ it becomes $n=A$ for $k=1$ I guess.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. Why  is my equation (4) wrong for $\theta(\text{n})=\pi\text{k}$??

Comment: @JanEerland You are looking for the maximum of $G$. The equation $G'=0$ gives you all critical points, which are both max and min. The maximum is at $k\pi$ for *even* $k$, while odd $k$ correspond to the minimum.

Comment: Ahh of course! Thanks for this explanation!!!